# how to (organize) the interaction between the Android UI (HTML, CSS) and native code (Java)?

Tags: java, android, html, css, native-code

Good afternoon.

I hasten to add that I am new to developing for Android. I am writing a geolocation service (application).

Standard elements of the user who provides Google does not suit me. In many of the Internet once faced with information which says that you can write a user interface for Android using CSS and html.

After reading a lot of information on this topic, I realized that Most developers tend to use frameworks (PhoneGap. ..). But this approach does not suit me, for two reasons:

1. javascript - it is used everywhere, and I do not know
2. This absence of adequate (understandable) documentation or guides for frameworks.

It is for these reasons that I'm wondering whether it is possible to write the user interface using html and CSS, and all the features in Java without using frameworks.

As communication between fallback interface and native code, even with the assistance of javascript, but without the use of frameworks.

P.S. I am not good in English - I hope you have understood the point of my question. I hope for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get where native-code gets in.

Comment: @HericDenis: In this case, I mean that is a java

Comment: well, I think native-code tag is not applicable here, since it't not even your question's focus, and Java isn't native (at least at my point of view).

Comment: @HericDenisYou: you have a right to their point of view. Yet for Android Java (backend) + XML (frontend) is a classical approach.

Comment: Okay than, that was just because I thought the native term was used to reference just languages like C, I was just intrigued (:

Answer (score 0):

Normally an Android app defines UI in Android-specific XML and the code is in Java or, if really necessary, C/C++.

Probably you could use a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) in your Android application which will display an html page from your `assets` directory.

Such html page can have javascript in it which will invoke some hooks in your code. It's described in the book [The Busy Coder's Guide to Advanced Android Development](http://commonsware.com/AdvAndroid/) Chapter 1, I believe

Comment: thanks for the advice, I hope this book will help me, if not in this matter in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can.
your html+css will all be in a webview and there're elements like the webview client that can communicate with what's inside the webview.

But I would like to leave you with a warning:
Every single web based app IS slower and with a poorer interface than proper native apps. Also, without the use of a framework you still will have to know a good portion of the native stuff.

Comment: What do you advise me to do - to customize the standard user interface elements or to know the depth of a framework?

Comment: I'm usually from the philosophy to do stuff the proper way. But that's very personal opinion. So just go for the books, tutorials, etc, and learn it.